# How to create SQL Database from Linq2Sql Model

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to create a SQL DB from a Linq2Sql model?  I managed to lose a DB for something I started building a year ago, but have the Linq2Sql model.  If this is possible, what are the steps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this

[How to: Dynamically Create a Database (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420.aspx)

```
YourDataContext db = new YourDataContext ("C:\\YourDB.mdf");
db.CreateDatabase();
```

Comment: Whoever just put a -1 on this should be kicked off of SO for life!  This is totally the answer!

Comment: I just added the code sample I used to get the MDF created...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this but I believe huagati can do this.

http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/

Answer (score 0):

please see the below links :

http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Product.aspx?lang=en&pid=55&tid=linqtosqlsynchronization

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQ_to_SQL_Database_Sync.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420.aspx

from MSDN :

```
public class MyDVDs : DataContext
{
    public Table<DVD> DVDs;
    public MyDVDs(string connection) : base(connection) { }
}

[Table(Name = "DVDTable")]
public class DVD
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string Title;
    [Column]
    public string Rating;
}
```